# JPA: How to fill related entity after the master is inserted

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping

I have two tables called `SL_DOCUMENT` and `SL_PROPOSE`. The `SL_DOCUMENT` has its own ID (`ID_DOCUMENT`) and a foreign key to `SL_PROPOSE` (`ID_PROPOSE`). The `SL_PROPOSE` ID column is `ID_PROPOSE`. The particularity is that `SL_PROPOSE` ID value is actually the `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_DOCUMENT` value. i.e., after a new `SL_DOCUMENT` is inserted, the related `SL_PROPOSE` should be inserted with the `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_DOCUMENT` as ID and later the same value should be used in `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_PROPOSE` column.

I did my JPA mapping as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_DOCUMENT")
public class DocumentORM {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENT")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT", sequenceName = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "document", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
//  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROPOSE", updatable = false)
    private ProposeORM propose;

    // ...

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_PROPOSE")
public class ProposeORM  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PROPOSE")
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PROPOSE")
    private DocumentORM document;

    // ...

    public ProposeORM(DocumentORM document) {
        super();
        this.document = document;
        this.document.setPropositura(this);
    }

}
```

To create the new instances of of DocumentORM and ProposeORM:

```
DocumentORM document = new DocumentORM();
ProposeORM propose = new ProposeORM(document);
```

And finally to insert the new Document with ProposeORM:

```
this.documentoDAO.insert(document);
```

When I really insert a document, according the snippets above, I see in the console (Websphere 8.5) the INSERT commands for the `SL_DOCUMENT`, `SL_PROPOSE` running correctly. However, when I see the tables, the column `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_PROPOSE` is still `NULL`. Even If I uncomment the `@JoinColumn` annotation over DocumentORM.propose, the `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_PROPOSE` column continues to be not filled.

The ideal would be if `SL_DOCUMENT` had a discriminator column and ProposeORM was a DocumentORM subclass, using the `JOINED` InheritanceType (there are other tables with the same kind of relationship with `SL_DOCUMENT`). However, these are legacy tables and it is not possible to change it.

So, what is the alternative to fill `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_PROPOSE`? A workaround I was thinking is fill this column using a native SQL. Do you have better ideas?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 1):

The solution I see is to make ProposeORM's ID not auto-generated, since you always want it to have the ID of the document it's linked to, AND still have a join column in the document table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_DOCUMENT")
public class DocumentORM {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENT")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT", sequenceName = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENT")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROPOSE")
    private ProposeORM propose;

    // ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_PROPOSE")
public class ProposeORM  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PROPOSE")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = propose)
    private DocumentORM document;

    // ...

    public ProposeORM(DocumentORM document) {
        super();
        this.id = document.getId();
        this.document = document;
        this.document.setPropositura(this);
    }
}
```

You'll have to persist the document first, flush the EntityManager to make sure the document has a generated ID, and then persist the propose and set it into the document.

Comment: I did this: after call the insert DAO method, I flushed the Entity manager as you suggested. Next, I called a method which updated the `SL_DOCUMENT.ID_PROPOSE` through a Native SQL and flushed the Entity manager again.